# I have an error for discord.js rpc! Can someone please help me?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord-rpc

This is my error:

```
(node:42087) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not connect
    at Socket.onerror (/Users/vinesh/RPC/node_modules/discord-rpc/src/transports/ipc.js:32:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:42087) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:42087) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My code:

```
const RPC = require('discord-rpc');
const client = new RPC.Client({ transport: 'ipc' });
client.on('ready', () =>
{
    client.request('SET_ACTIVITY', {
        pid: process.pid,
        activity: {
            assets: {
                large_image: 'Coding'
            },
            details: 'Coding',
            buttons: [
                { label: 'Emperor', url: 'https://dsc.gg/invite-emperor' },
                { label: 'https://dsc.gg/invite-emperor', url: 'https://dsc.gg/invite-emperor' }
            ]
        }
    });
    console.log('started!');
});
client.login({ clientId: 'My_ID' });
```

How do I fix this? Is it because the code is old? I don't know why it does that. I did `npm init -y`, `npm install discord`, and `npm install discord-rpc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running the web browser version of Discord, RPC will not work. Instead download Discord for Desktop which is [here](https://discord.com).

If you are running Discord desktop then try this code. Also remember to add your assets in `https://discord.com/developers/applications/Application_ID/rich-presence/assets` and make sure they are the same name in application and code. You need `large_text` so don't remove it.

```js
var rpc = require("discord-rpc")
const client = new rpc.Client({ transport: 'ipc' })
client.on('ready', () => {
    client.request('SET_ACTIVITY', {
        pid: process.pid,
        activity : {
            details : "Coding",
            assets : {
                large_image : "Your Image",
                large_text : "Your Status"
            },
            buttons : [{label : "Emperor" , url : "https://dsc.gg/invite-emperor"},{label : "Invite 2?",url : "https://dsc.gg/invite-emperor"}]
        }
    })
})
client.login({ clientId : "CLIENT_ID" }).catch(console.error);
```